# Explanation of difference in one variable by baseline difference

Tags: regression, anova, t-test

Say I have 2 sample datasets, A and B, each with sample size 200.
For both samples, I have data on 2 particular continuous variables (let's call them X and Y). After performing a t-test, I found that X of sample A is statistically different from X of sample B. Similarly, Y of sample A is also statistically different from Y of sample B.

With this, what should I do to check whether the difference in Y can be explained by the difference in X.

Comment: The preliminary testing seems to have no bearing on your pertinent question. If you are concerned as to whether sample A can be pooled with sample B (or not), then there is a different question of whether effect modification is present.

Answer (score 0):

#### F-test

Consider $Y_{new} = Y_1 - Y_2$ and $X_{new} = X_1 - X_2$ which are the new $Y$ and new  $X$.

- New Model 1 :

  Now fit a new model with $Y_{new}$ as response and $X_{new}$ as predictor.
  $$Y_{new} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 * X_{new}$$
- New Model 2 :

  Now fit a new model with $Y_{new}$ as response and only intercept.
  $$Y_{new} = \beta_0$$

Compare these 2 models using an  F-test with following hypothesis,
$$H_0 : \beta_1 = 0 \quad (X_{new}\quad not\quad important)$$
$$H_A : \beta_1 \neq 0 \quad (X_{new}\quad is\quad important)$$

In the F-test if $p \leq 0.05 $ , then the $X_{new}$ explains $Y_{new}$   i.e Difference in X explains difference in Y.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, if the 2 samples are unpaired, then how should i go about getting Ynew and Xnew?